# React Native: What is the way to make the second picker (selectedValue2) works?

Tags: javascript, react-native

What is the way to make the second picker (selectedValue2)  works ?
When i try to change the second picker so its not change its value and i don't understand why .
I would love to know what the reason is and how I handle it .

```js
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import { Platform, ScrollView, StyleSheet, Text, View } from 'react-native';
import { Picker } from '@react-native-community/picker';

const Settings = () => {
  const [selectedValue, setSelectedValue] = useState('java');
  const [selectedValue2, setSelectedValue2] = useState('ddd');

  return (
    <>
      <View style={{ marginTop: 20 }}>
        <Text style={styles.text}>choose</Text>
      </View>
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <Picker
          selectedValue={selectedValue}
          style={{
            height: 50,
            width: 150,
            justifyContent: 'flex-end',
            // marginRight: 100,
          }}
          onValueChange={(itemValue, itemIndex) => setSelectedValue(itemValue)}
        >
          <Picker.Item label="Java" value="java" />
          <Picker.Item label="JavaScript" value="js" />
        </Picker>
        <Picker
          selectedValue2={selectedValue2}
          style={{
            height: 50,
            width: 150,
            justifyContent: 'flex-end',
            // marginRight: 100,
          }}
          onValueChange={(itemValue, itemIndex) => setSelectedValue2(itemValue)}
        >
          <Picker.Item label="sss" value="ss" />
          <Picker.Item label="zzz" value="zz" />
        </Picker>
      </View>
    </>
  );
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem in the second picker is that there is no such property `selectedValue2` on the Picker component. That is the name of your local state variable, but the property of the component is `selectedValue`. This means your changes aren't propagated to the component. Here is the correct way:

```
  <Picker
          selectedValue={selectedValue2}
          ...
```